# LoadLibrary taking a LPCTSTR

Tags: c++, windows, dll, loadlibrary

I want to develop a plugin system using LoadLibrary. 
My problem is: I want my function to take a `const char*` and `LoadLibrary` takes a `LPCTSTR`. 
I had the *bright* idea to do `(LPCSTR)path` which kept giving me a module not found error.  
Current code is below.  If I uncomment the `widepath = L..` line it works fine. I've read solutions using MFC but I'd like to not use MFC.

Current code:

```
bool PluginLoader::Load(char *path)
{
    path = "Release\\ExamplePlugin.dll";
    LPCTSTR widepath = (LPCTSTR)path;
    //widepath = L"Release\\ExamplePlugin.dll";

    HMODULE handle = LoadLibrary(widepath);
    if (handle == 0)
    {
        printf("Path: %s\n",widepath );
        printf("Error code: %d\n", GetLastError());

        return false;
    }

    int (*load_callback)() = (int (*)()) GetProcAddress(handle, "_plugin_start@0");

    if (load_callback == 0)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return load_callback() == LOAD_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use LoadLibraryA(), it takes a const char*.

Winapi functions that take strings exist in two versions, an A version that takes an Ansi string and a W version that takes a wide string.  There's a macro for the function name, like LoadLibrary, that expands to either the A or the W flavor, depending if UNICODE is #defined.  You are compiling your program with that #define in effect, so you get LoadLibraryW().  Simply cheat and use LoadLibraryA() explicitly.

Comment: That's why this web site exists, it covers the unintuitive ;-)

Answer (score 8):

I suggest you using `TCHAR` and `LoadLibrary` instead of using manually `char` or `wchar_t` and `LoadLibraryA` or `LoadLibraryW` to make a generic application, both for *UNICODE* and *ASCII* characters.

So you could do:

`TCHAR x[100] = TEXT("some text");`

I suggest you reading [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/76252/What-are-TCHAR-WCHAR-LPSTR-LPWSTR-LPCTSTR-etc.aspx). `LPCTSTR` is a `const TCHAR*`.

Why use `LoadLibrary` instead of `LoadLibraryW` or `LoadLibraryA`? To support both *UNICODE* and *ASCII* without creating two different programs, one to work with `char` and the other with `wchar_t`.

Also, take a look at what Microsoft says about it: [Conventions for Function Prototypes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd317766%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you continue to use a `char *` for the parameter, you'll run into cases where an unusual character is used in the filename and the LoadLibrary will fail. Change the function to use wchar_t instead, and while you're at it make the parameter `const` since you're not modifying the string.

```
bool PluginLoader::Load(const wchar_t *path)
```

I think you'll find that LPCTSTR on 32-bit Windows is a macro that expands to `const wchar_t *` when the program options are set to Unicode.

Answer (score 0):

The approved method with `LoadLibrary` is to *not* use a `char const *`, but instead use a `TCHAR const *`, and use the `_T` macro on all literals:

```
bool PluginLoader::Load(TCHAR const *path) {

    path = _T("Release\\ExamplePlugin.dll");

    HMODULE handle = LoadLibrary(path);
    if (handle == 0)
    {
        _tprintf(_T("Path: %s\n"),widepath );
        _tprintf(_T("Error code: %d\n"), GetLastError());

        return false;
    }

    int (*load_callback)() = (int (*)()) GetProcAddress(handle, _T("_plugin_start@0"));

    if (load_callback == 0)
    {    
        return false;
    }    
    return load_callback() == LOAD_SUCCESS;
}
```

This will automatically use `LoadLibraryW` when `_UNICODE`/`UNICODE` are defined, and `LoadLibraryA` when they're not. Likewise, `_T` will give narrow or wide string literals on the same basis, so it all stays in sync.

I *generally* prefer to use the `W` suffixed functions explicitly, and use the `L` prefix on string literals. Windows works almost exclusively with wide strings internally anyway, so the version `A`-suffixed versions that take narrow string literals are mostly small stubs that convert their arguments to wide strings, then call the wide string version. Using the wide string version directly saves both time and memory.

Narrow string support in Windows was originally there primarily for compatibility with the long-since defunct Windows 95/98/SE/Me line that lacked wide string support. Those have been gone for quite a while, so about the only reason to use narrow literals now is because that's what you're being supplied from some outside source.